# Excel VBA - Clear Column contents from row 2 down

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to clear column contents from row 2 down on a VBA script which I am running, the piece of code below is how I am going about this.

This doesn't appear to be working, but no syntax issues or error messages.  Are there issues with this code?

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Sub Loader()

Dim wb3 As Workbook
Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook

wb3.Worksheets("Config Sheet").Range("F2").End(xlDown).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try expanding the range to be more than just a single cell.

```
with wb3.Worksheets("Config Sheet")
    .Range("F2:F" & .range("F2").End(xlDown).row).ClearContents
end with
```

If you go to the *Config Sheet* worksheet, select F2 and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, you will only have the last cell selected. The above modification is the same as if you had tapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach doesn't work, I tried to change clearcontents to clear as well, still doesn't work.  I would like it to be dynamic but I may need to go with a static range to work around it

Comment: What range does `.Range("F2:F" & .Range("F2").End(xlDown)).address` return?

Comment: @PootyToot - Just tested it. Worked fine. I strongly suspect that the *Config Sheet* you are targeting is not in the same workbook as that code module. `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook that the code module resides in.